# Login authenticate is not working in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to make a login system which will authenticate wether user is in db or not. But it doesn't authenticate the user. I don't know what i am doing wrong and I really don't have idea how this authenticate will check the model db info.

Please explain me what authenticate does and what will it do right now and please help me in fixing the problem

Here,s my register view

```
def register(request):
    user = UserProfile()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user.username = request.POST.get('Username')
        user.email = request.POST.get('email')
        user.password = request.POST.get('Password')
        user.confirm_password = request.POST.get('ConfirmPassword')
        user.profession = request.POST.get('Proffesionname')
        user.save()
        return redirect(reverse('login'))
    return render(request,'social_app/register.html',{'user':user})
```

Here is the login views

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('Password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
            else:
                return  HttpResponse('User no longer active')
        else:
            print(f'username :{username}')
    return render(request,'social_app/login.html')
```

Here's the UserProfile model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    confirm_password = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: Don't write your login code and model to store passwords like this, it's insecure. Django comes with an [auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/) app to handle passwords and login. Use it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Alasdair explained, you should use the [Django auth functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/)

Maybe this app is helpful for you [Django Allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)